# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: parse-platform, trigger.io

Version 2.0.0

I'm trying to use the parse object as per the docs: https://trigger.io/modules/parse/current/docs/index.html

```
forge.parse.push.subscribe(...)
```

The error I am getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` which. So the parse property is not set. I have heard that this is a problem where the config is not set correctly, but setting parse up via the toolkit doesn't seem to have any effect and the parse property is still not set.

My config:

```
{
  ...
  "modules": {
    ...
    "parse": {
      "version": "2.0",
      "config": {
        "clientKey": "xxx",
        "applicationId": "xxx"
      }
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Forge signature:

```
{
  button: Object
  config: Object
  document: Object
  enableDebug: function (){h.debug=true;h.priv.call("internal.showDebugWarning", },null,null);h.priv.call("internal.hideDebugWarning",{},null,null)}
  event: Object
  file: Object
  geolocation: Object
  internal: Object
  is: Object
  logging: Object
  message: Object
  notification: Object
  prefs: Object
  reload: Object
  request: Object
  tabs: Object
  tools: Object
  __proto__: Object
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use Parse on a non-mobile target (probably web). Parse push notifications are only available on Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
forge.partners.parse.push.subscribe("offers",
function () {
  forge.logging.info("subscribed to offers push notifications!");
},
function (err) {
  forge.logging.error("error subscribing to offers notifications: "+
    JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined`

Comment: Please read this https://trigger.io/docs/v1.4/api/modules/parse.html Are you sure you have all set up as the link says?

Comment: `You are currently viewing docs for a non-current version, the information below may not apply to the current core version of Forge.`

Comment: can u share your html file

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, but I'm not sure what you hope to glean from it?